# Proving a certain set has a supremum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ denote a continuous function defined on $[a,b]$. Let $M$ be $\sup f([a,b])$, and let $A=\{x\in[a,b] |f(x)=M\}$. Prove that $A$ has a supremum $S$, and that $S \in A$. Does $\max (A)$ exist?

Obviously, we're going to need to use the intermediate value theorem as well as Weierstrass' theorems here, but in a clever way. Not sure how exactly. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Not really a clever way. You'll need Weierstrass for a technical, albeit important, initial detail, and then just the definition of supremum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $A$ is bounded (it's a subset of $[a,b]$) and nonempty (**WHY**?), proving it has a supremum should be relatively easy (since every non-empty bounded set has one).

Also, the question "Does $\max(A)$ exist?" is easy to answer once we know that the supremum of $A$ is an element of $A$ (the answer is yes - a set has a maximum if and only if it contains its own supremum)

---

So, all we have left to do is to prove $S\in A$.

To do that, the best way I see would be to go by contradiction. Assume that $S$ is not in $A$. Then there must exist an infinite sequence $a_1,a_2\dots$ such that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=S$$

that satisfies the condition $\forall i: a_i\in A$ (clearly, that means $a_i\neq S$).

1. Now, look at the values $f(a_1), f(a_2)\dots$. What are they equal to?
2. Using 1., what is $$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(a_n)$$ equal to?
3. What can you then say about $$f(\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n)$$ (remember, $f$ is continuous!)?

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if wrong:

$f$ continuous on $[a,b]$ , interval closed and bounded.

$\rightarrow$  $B :=${$f(x)|x \in [a,b]$} is bounded,

and

$f(x)$ attains its maximum $M$ on $[a,b]$,

i.e. there is a point $c \in [a,b]$

with $f(c) = M = \max(B)$.

$A =$

{$x | x \in [a,b]$ and $f(x) = f(c) =M$}

$= f^{-1}(${$M$}$)$  $\ne \emptyset$.

$A$ as a subset of $[a,b]$ is bounded,

$\rightarrow$  $\sup(A)$ exists.

Consider: $A= f^{-1}(${$M$}$)$.

Since $f$ is continuous  and {$M$} is closed,

$\rightarrow$ $A = f^{-1}(${$M$}$)$ is closed;

$\rightarrow$  every limit point of $A$

is a point of $A $.

$\sup(A)$  is a limit point of $A$,

$\rightarrow$  $\sup(A)  \in A$.

Comment: Do you mean $f^{-1}(M)$?

Comment: mfl. sure, noticed it, and fixed it.Hopefully the answer is OK now.Thanks, Peter.